# How to find an unknown integer

Tags: algorithm, search

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find an unknown integer, given a function that tells me whether it is in a given closed interval or not. I.e., I am looking for an implementation of this signature:

```kotlin
fun findInt(isInClosedInterval: (Pair<Int,Int>) -> Boolean): Int
```

I might be able to come up with an algorithm myself, but I would guess that one already exists, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. It would be ideal if you could point me to a function in a library on the Java platform, but only the name of an algorithm or mathematical function would also be appreciated.

I was thinking about a solution involving binary search, but it seems that it is only applicable if you want to find the position of a known element, while my element (the integer) is unknown.

Comment: A more fitting keyword than binary-search, imho, would be [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) as you probably need to initialize some guaranteed-to-contain interval first. Then it's probably simply branching on each half until the half is a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find an implementation in a library, I created one myself. It can be found in the package `com.marcoeckstein.klib.algorithm` in the multiplatform library [kotlin-lib](https://github.com/marco-eckstein/kotlin-lib). I have slightly changed the signature as opposed to my question:

```kotlin
fun findNumber(isNumberInRange: (IntRange) -> Boolean): Int?
```

These unit tests demonstrate how to use it:

```kotlin
@Test
fun findNumber_finds_number() {
    TestData.integers.forAll { number ->
        findNumber { it.contains(number) } shouldBe number
    }
}

@Test
fun findNumber_returns_null_when_there_is_no_number() {
    findNumber { false } shouldBe null
}
```

I think what I am doing in my implementation is the exponential search that [sascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320035/sascha) mentioned in his comment. At least the idea is the same, though I am not sure if it exactly matches the definition of exponential search.

I also found the implementation of binary search that I was looking for, one that does not require you to explicitly give the element you are searching for. It is in the Kotlin standard library, and I had overlooked it previously.

```kotlin
public fun <T> List<T>.binarySearch(
    fromIndex: Int = 0, 
    toIndex: Int = size, 
    comparison: (T) -> Int // Implicitly specifies the element to be found.
                           // Returns 1, -1 or 0.
): Int
```

I could not use it for my problem though, because it works on a list, and to find an arbitrary integer, I would have needed a list with every integer in it, which leads to a heap space requirement of multiple GB. So I implemented a binary search that works on an `IntRange`, which can also be used from the new library.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow, you are looking for an algorithm that finds a random integer?

I don't know of one in a library, but the best approach to build it so that it's as fast as possible consistently is to follow the example here. It explains why this approach works.
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/intro-to-algorithms/a/a-guessing-game

If you're looking for a more exact solution, I suggest giving more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Correct. In the original problem, I have a little bit of knowledge about the random number, but I didn't want to complicate my question. Anyway: The number is likely within range of a few hundreds around zero, but isInClosedInterval() is extremely expensive, so linear search is still practically impossible.